# SQL, СУБД и их особенности

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

Новичок в этом всё поэтому хотелось бы спросить:

> SQL - это язык структурированных запросов применяемый для создания,
>   модификации и управления данными в реляционной базе данных,
>   управляемой соответствующей системой управления базами данных.

Давайте пройдемся по СУБД: 
1. MySQL - Реляционная система управления базами данных. 
2. PostgreSQL - объектно-реляционная система управления базами данных. 
3. MS SQL - система управления реляционными базами данных. 
Хотелось бы спросить: 
1. В каждой СУБД свой язык SQL? В моем понимании и маленьком опыте я заметил что SQL это общий язык запросов, а в каждой СУБД он реализован по-разному с маленькими своими изменениями, да?

Comment: да, есть стандарты, типа SQL-92, и более поздние, по большей части они выполняются, но не все. по идее, запросы должны работать везде одинаково, чтобы можно было просто поменять БД. по факту, работают базовые вещи, а чего-то может не быть. например, LIMIT работает в MySQL, он очень популярен. в MSSQL LIMIT нет. Есть залезть в историю, были войны БД, кто-то делает какую-либо фишку, на этой БД делают огромное приложение. И все, с этой БД уже не слезешь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть стандартный SQL. Он развивается и каждые несколько лет выходит новый стандарт, дополняющий предыдущие. Каждая СУБД в разной степени реализует какой-то из стандартов и добавляет свои нестандартные особенности, формируя диалект SQL.

- PostgreSQL почти полностью реализует стандарт SQL:2011.
- MySQL до версии 8 даже SQL-92 поддерживала не полностью. Не знаю, как
  сейчас обстоят дела. И боюсь, что это будет сложно выяснить, в
  документации по этому вопросу только уклончивые общие фразы.
- Microsoft в своём SQL Server как всегда выбирает "особый путь",
  поэтому их диалект столько всего добавляет к стандарту, что даже
  собственное название заимел - [T-SQL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL).

[Таблица совместимости](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_compliance) позволяет получить общее представление о том, кто хорошо реализует стандарты, кто не очень, а кто настолько плохо, что даже информацию скрывает.

Comment: Спасибо большое, как раз услышал, то что хотел. Вы меня выручаете каждый день, спасибо большое еще раз!

Answer (score 3):

`SQL` в общем - это серия стандартов под эгидой `ISO/IEC`. В целом для СУБД некорректно заявлять поддержку `SQL`, **противоречащую** стандарту. Но является нормальным не реализовывать все части стандарта. И обычно никак не удаётся обойтись без реализации своих собственных дополнений для синтаксиса.

Простой и банальный пример дополнения синтаксиса - в стандарте нет `create index`. Вообще. Есть только синтаксис для primary key и unique constraint, а вторичных индексов нет. Но без них хорошую базу не сделать. Приходится добавлять синтаксис. Но разные базы разрабатываются разными людьми, обладают разными особенностями и неизбежно получается различающийся синтаксис.

Другой пример - в стандарте долгое времени не было способа ограничить размер select. Тот самый `limit ... offset ...`, но который реализован по разному в разных базах. Некоторые из вариантов синтаксиса другие базы добавляли как альтернативу своему, например исторически в mysql сделали `limit x,y` синтаксис, но затем для совместимости с postgresql добавили и `limit ... offset ...`.

Встречаются и нарушения либо отклонения от стандартов. Например, более строгая обработка синтаксиса, в принципе допустимого в стандарте, но недопустимая в реализации.

Как итог - стандарт как бы есть и многие задачи решаются схожим образом и СУБД ведут себя схожим образом, но полагаться на это весьма не рекомендуется. Могут быть расхождения как в самом синтаксисе, так и в поведении при том же самом синтаксисе.

---

И отдельная [боль](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/878syu5j4i.fsf%40news-spur.riddles.org.uk) разработчиков СУБД

> since when has the SQL standard ever been clear?

Стандарт есть, но он зачастую не однозначен и не очевиден в своих формулировках. Определённая часть расхождений поведения связана именно с этим. Разработчики одной СУБД прочли стандарт и поняли его так, разработчики другой - поняли иначе.